# ActionScript 3 - Detecting nearest hit point from a MovieClip's registration point touching many others movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have a movieclip called ray. User can rotate ray movieclip. There are surrounding walls and few objects - all movieclips. Now i want if ray touches any of the wall or other object, it should end there. So basically I want to detect the hit points of ray movieclip with different objects and then want to calculate nearest hit point from the registration point of ray. Accordingly I can re-size the ray movieclip.

I can find if ray hits any wall or other objects. But don't know how to find touch point of the object and the distance from ray origin.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hitTestPoint` along with `for` loop and `break` the loop when ray touches the object.

Also, generate that ray `MovieClip` using AS3 code.

Following link shows one example, (although, you will need to convert the rotating ray in the example to suit your need.)

[It shows ray generated and collision with objects](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=active%20tuts%20laser&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/laser-generator-obstacles-and-accurate-hit-detection/&ei=i2VVUZaDG4SOrQfh9oBA&usg=AFQjCNELNpl-fhJ19xw60DtoG-DcuB1SIA)

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Rajneesh for quick and effective solution.